# How can I correctly set and use a Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I want to set this structure:

```
0:[
    "name"="My Name",
    "description"="Some Description"
  ],
1:[
    "name"="Some Name"
    "description"="Some other Description"
  ]
]
```

Here is how I am initiating my dictionary:

```
var topStandbyUsers = [Int:[String:String]]()
```

Here is how I am setting it (also errors here):

```
self.topStandbyUsers[0] = ["fullname"="My Name","description"="Some description"] // this gives me a error
```

I want to be able to access it later doing something like:

```
self.topStandByUsers[0]["name"] // I want it to give "My Name"
```

Don't have much experience in using dictionaries, wanted some clarification on what I'm doing wrong and also how to use dictionaries correctly.

Comment: Why do you want an integer key of the outer dictionary, vs using an array?

Comment: @HotLicks I wasn't sure if its possible to call a dictionary by using an index. I wanted to access a piece of the data when I go through the dictionary one at a time. They would be separate calls so I wouldn't be able to go through the dictionary using a for loop.

Comment: Well, you don't "call" anything, and you certainly don't have to go through an array with a loop.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks, your idea makes perfect sense and is definitely another approach I could use. I just tunneled in on using a dictionary the whole way through. Do you know if there is any performance implications or a difference from using one vs the other?

Comment: Generally speaking, the array is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the assignment operator you are using in the following code:

```
self.topStandbyUsers[0] = ["fullname"="My Name","description"="Some description"]
```

Change that to:

```
self.topStandbyUsers[0] = ["fullname":"My Name","description":"Some description"]
```

You can retrieve the value using:

```
var data = self.topStandbyUsers[0]!
println(data["fullname"])
```

Comment: That removed the error, thanks. How would I go about accessing the first index's "fullname"?

Comment: @jshah: I have added the code for retrieving data. Please check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks. I have a question, why do I have to do 2 statements. Why can I just do var fullname = self.topStandbyUsers[indexPath.row]["fullname"]! ? (Gives me an error)

Comment: your `!` sing is not on the same place

Comment: @jshah: You can use like : var fullname = self.topStandbyUsers[indexPath.row]!["fullname"]!

Answer (score 1):

I see you have already accepted an answer, but I still think like Hot Licks, you should look at using an array of dicts, instead of a dictionary of dictionaries.

Basically:

```
var topStandbyUsers = [[String:String]]()
```

gets you the same thing except it is an array.  You could add dicts the same way or using append.

```
self.topStandbyUsers[0] = ["fullname":"My Name","description":"Some description"]
self.topStandbyUsers.append(["fullname":"My Name","description":"Some description"])
```

then you retrieving data would work like

```
self.topStandByUsers[0]["name"]!
```

Comment: This is the way I was originally imagining to do it. Thanks for this, I am probably going to implement it this way. Upvoted you but going to leave the other answer as the accepted answer because it answers the original question.